# Why does the width of the auto-suggest dropdown box not match the width of the combobox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox, autosuggest

In VB.NET for the combo box, I have set the autocomplete mode  to "SuggestAppend" and autocomplete source to "ListItems". Its working as expected. But the width of the autosuggest dropdown box is not same as that of combo box and so it looks weird.

I tried changing the value dropdown width property but it changes the value of normal dropdown box (seen after clicking down arrow on combobox), and not the autosuggest dropdown box.

So what code or property needs to be set to make autosuggest dropdown box the same width as that of combobox width?
[image: This image shows difference between the width of autosuggest dropdownbox and that of combobox width]

[image: This images show normal dropdown box , width of which is controlled by dropdown width propery of combobox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look real closely and you'll notice that its width is user-customizable. The resizing grip at the lower right corner is the dead giveaway:

[image: resizing grip indicated with a freehand circle]

There's no built-in option to specify the width, and that's by design. Under the covers, the `ComboBox` control actually uses the [`SHAutoCompleteAPI` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862.aspx) to implement this functionality. The auto-suggest box always displays with the last width chosen by the user. It can just as easily appear much *larger* than the width of the combo box.

If you really wanted to do this, you could subclass the `ComboBox` control, P/Invoke a bunch of functions from the Windows API, and get the handle to the auto-suggestion box window, which you could then resize. But the code is ugly, and it's hardly worth the trouble. Sample code is available [on this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5d0e19bb-d5a2-444e-bda8-6774e9889963).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i used re-size grip option suggested but if it is used then the height also remains constant along-with width. In normal case  height is adjusted as per the number of element in list. Is there work around for this?

Comment: @vai: I'm not sure what you mean. Neither the width nor the height are user-configurable, at least not without a lot of work (see the link in my answer). The resize grip will let the user resize both the width *and* the height of the box. It's exactly the same UI that's found in every Open/Save dialog box. The user either knows how it works, or doesn't care.